# Searching across multiple indexes in Python 2D list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

I've created a simple database in the form of a 2D list where you can add a record, find a record, delete a record and print all records.

```
record_db = []
#this is where I have the menu function
```

an example of an entry in the database is:

```
['Sam', 'Smith', 25, 99.4]
#string, string, integer, float
```

Now my question is when I go to do "find a record"

I have this:

```
def find_a_record():
    name = input("Enter the last name of record to find: ")
    if name in record_db:
        print('The following record was found in the database:')
        print(#this is where the record would go)
    else
        print('does not exist')
```

but then when you search a name that is in the database, it says 'does not exist' always.

I know this has something to do with the indices because if I do:

```
if name in record_db[0]
```

instead of

```
if name in record_db
```

It will confirm only the first record in the database.

My question is how do I write the code so that it checks all of the indexes in the entire database?

Comment: So is `record_db` a 2D list?

Comment: @m_callens yes sorry, probably would have been helpful to mention. I'm very new to this

Comment: Use a dict of dicts not lists and lookup with the key, your structure is not suitable for what you are trying to do

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you've provided, record_db is a list of lists.

When checking `if name in record_db` it will only check at the first level. Which will always return false. Since no strings are in the list record_db, only lists.

Therefore, you want to iterate through your record_db using a for-loop and then check if `name` is in the entry.

```
record_db = [] # created as empty
# new entries are added for test case
# each entry is a list
record_db.append( ['Sam', 'Smith', 25, 99.4] )
record_db.append( ['Paul', 'Roberts', 35, 96.4] )
record_db.append( ['Bob', 'Sanders', 23, 89.4] )
record_db.append( ['Phil', 'Smith', 27, 95.4] )

def find_a_record():
    name = input("Enter the last name of record to find: ")
    results = []
    # for each entry in record_db
    for entry in record_db:
        # check if name is in that entry
        # will append all matching entry to results
        if name in entry:
            results.append(entry)
    # If results found
    if results:
        print('The following record(s) were found in the database:')
        print(results)
    else:
        print('does not exist')
```

You can also replace `print(results)` with the following if you want each record found printed on a new line instead of just printing the list.

```
for record in results:
    print(record)
```

Example input and output for both True and False cases

```
#Input
Enter the last name of record to find: Smith

#Output
The following record(s) were found in the database:
['Sam', 'Smith', 25, 99.4]
['Phil', 'Smith', 27, 95.4]

#Input
Enter the last name of record to find: Thing
does not exist
```

**On a side note**

If you want to make certain that only the last name is being checked then replace `if name in entry` with `if name == entry[1]`

Comment: Basically, what you've (re)written is Python's built-in `filter` function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: Well firstly I'm providing code adding on to the code provided. Secondly, this is more an alternate to filter as many people are unaware or not sure how to use it. Thirdly there is already a response concerning the use of filter.

Comment: That's why I add the pointer to `filter`'s documentation. Learning how to use the built-in functions is time well spent and a rewarding exercise, I'd imagine.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest - I think - would be to filter your list of records based on a condition:

```
filter(lambda record: name in record[0], record_db)
```

What this does is filter (...) your list or records (which is `record_db`) and for each element in that list executes the `lambda` (anonymous function) and only returns the items for which that expression is true.

In this case, it tests if the first element of your record contains the string indentified by the variable `name`.

If you want to search for last name in stead, change to `name in record[1]`

More interestingly, you can make more complex filters:

```
filter(lambda record: name in record[1] and age<record[2], record_db)
```

to `query` by last name and age.

Answer (score 0):

Because the first and last name of the artists are in separate indices of the record, you will need to search each record and compare the entered name to the concatenation of the two values:

```
for record in record_db:
    if name == '{0} {1}'.format(record[0], record[1]):
        <YOU FOUND IT>
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, `record_db` is a list of lists, but `name` is a string. There are no strings in the list of lists. So you can loop through `record_db` and check each list inside `record_db`.